# YouTube API "q" Parameter Broken?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

According to the YouTube API documentation, the "q" parameter searches through the metadata for the videos. This includes the title, description, and keywords.

However, just recently (since yesterday to my knowledge) the "q" parameter is only searching the titles.

Here is the feed for NBA:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/nba/uploads

There is a video with the title "Top 5 Plays of the Night: April 16th" with the description "Check out the best plays from Tuesday`s action in the NBA".

If I search for "Tuesday" the video doesn't come up: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/nba/uploads?q=Tuesday

If I search for "Top" it does: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/nba/uploads?q=top

I believe Google monitors this forum. What has gone wrong? I really need to search all fields for my application. I've been using it for the past year or two and for it to suddenly just break is crippling! Please provide guidance.

Comment: Try: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/nba/uploads?q=Check%20out%20the%20best%20plays%20from%20Tuesday`s%20action%20in%20the%20NBA

Comment: alfasin, i have a trigger word in the description of videos for my application. While your example works, if I do a search for "check" or "out" or "Tuesday" from the example above, it doesn't work. It brings back other results, not the one I am looking for, like it would in the past.

Comment: That's because your search is too broad, you need to narrow it by supplying more keywords

Comment: Here is a less broad example: If I search for "7100" or "Austin" for Pizza Hut's youtube the respective video doesn't show up. http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pizzahut/uploads?q=7100 and http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pizzahut/uploads?q=Austin

Comment: However, if I type in "Greatness" which is in the title for the 7100 and Austin examples, it then comes up: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pizzahut/uploads?q=Greatness

Answer (score 0):

That does indeed appear to be broken. I know that YouTube doesn't publicly expose tags (keywords) anymore and now refers to them as tags so I am guessing this [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#qsp) is old. I would recommend that you switch to using [this query from the V3 Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) to get your desired results.